# pbs python Error: No module named _pbs

Tags: python, django, cluster-computing, pbs

I want to run [PyPBS](https://github.com/rauch/PyPBS) (A web interface for PBS torque). so I have installed all dependencies of it. And [pbs_python](https://github.com/VPAC/pbs_python) (wrapper class for the ​Torque C library) is one of them.
The problem is when I run django server, I get this error:

```
"No module named _pbs"
Error: 
Django Version: 1.4.20

Exception Type: ImportError

Exception Value: No module named _pbs

Exception Location: C:\Python272\lib\site-packages\pbs\pbs.py in swig_import_helper, line 18
```

Thanks to any help.

Comment: I have recently been trying to use the pbs_python library as well, I have been having issues with it. Were you able to fix this issue? I believe that there is supposed to be a file `_pbs.so` in the directory `C:\Python272\lib\site-packages\pbs\ ` - did you check there? If one isn't there, it's possible that pbs_python didn't install correctly. How did you install? Did you use the `./configure | make | make install` method? If so, was there a `building '_pbs' extension` line in the output?

Comment: @SheerSt, I get my mistake. tanks very well.